# Ctrl-S doesn't work as "save" anywhere in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, button

This is my first time posting here. I have been working with Linux not for a bit, but I'm still getting the hang of it sometimes.

At some given point in time my save combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> stopped working, not in internet browsers, not in Emacs, nor gedit.. doesn't work at all. I checked if the buttons work and they do, but the combinations doesn't. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

To be more precise, <kbd>Left Ctrl-S</kbd> doesn't work, but <kbd>Right Ctrl-S</kbd> works normally, which is weird..

Not sure if related, but:
I got this new laptop that has some extra keys and I wanted to assign a special function to them, so I played around with xbindkeys and it worked fine, but I don't know if it affected my combination..

Thank you all!

---

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64x on a Lenovo Thinkpad E540

Comment: Does left ctrl work in other combinations?

Comment: Yes, all other left and right ctrl combinations seem to work. I also looked at the existing shortcuts but found no match

Comment: Hm, not sure what else to add, but you could try running `xev` in a terminal, then confirming that left ctrl results in `keysym 0xffe3, Control_L`. Perhaps also test s (`keysym 0x73, s`) and the right control too (`keysym 0xffe4, Control_R`).

Comment: they all seem to be working fine when pressed separately. if i put in a combo Ctrl_R-s it just states those two separately, but if I press Ctrl_L-s, it says that i pressed Alt_L... and also something about Sys_Rec

Comment: Oh, that does seem odd. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what else to suggest. Hopefully someone else can help. Also, if disabling `xbindkeys` fixes it, you might want to investigate `xkb` instead (or the older `xmodmap`).

Comment: I figured it out. I switched the fn and ctrl key in the bios, and it stopped working, tho it's weird because other things still did work, that is why i didn't consider this being the reason. After switching back, everything seems to be in order. I had a couple of problems with Ubuntu now and I got a bitter taste in my mouth and want to switch back to LMint17, but I guess I'll give it another chance. Would you prefer LMint17?

Comment: Oh great! Please remember to answer it yourself below, and accept. It *is* really weird. TBH I moved from Mint to Ubuntu/Unity to Ubuntu/Gnome to Kubuntu and I'm now using KDE in Arch Linux. So perhaps I'm not the best to ask. :) I didn't much like either Mint or Ubuntu/Unity, and didn't stay long on either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems that on my Lenovo Thinkpad E540 the problem was the BIOS switching of Ctrl and Fn key.. It's still isnt clear to me why the other shortcuts with the fake Ctrl worked tho..

Thank you all!